# If you were writing an emulator in Java would you use ints or bytes for CPU registers and memory and why?

Tags: java, emulation

Firstly yes i know that ints are more native than bytes and that all math and logical operations on bytes are actually done on ints. This of course means that there is a cost of widening and narrowing if using bytes. However on the counterbalance this also means that memory bytes really hold bytes and not potentially some greater than byte value value, eg 256.

Im guessing in both cases there are pros and cons but in would i am after opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use whatever type made is easiest to emulate the the hardware in question.

if it was an 8-bit computer that would probably be bytes.  for something like an x86-64 i imagine a long (64 bits) would make more sense.  in both cases the chose size is more likely to match register operations and the size of data "words" transferred between cpu and memory:

> All general-purpose registers (GPRs) are expanded from 32 bits to 64
>   bits, and all arithmetic and logical operations, memory-to-register
>   and register-to-memory operations, etc., can now operate directly on
>   64-bit integers. Pushes and pops on the stack are always in 8-byte
>   strides, and pointers are 8 bytes wide.

[from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Architectural_features)

Comment: Even a 64 bit x86 still reads and writes 8 bit bytes. If you kept everything as 64 bit longs then you would have problems extracting and replacing real 8 bit bytes etc.

Comment: i said easiest, not "supports every operation with a single method in Java".

Comment: Sorry, i was thinking of memory not internal registers, good thing you clarified.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote a mips processor I used the class BitSet to hold the individual bits to make bit arrays easy to split up with the subset method. I wrote a class to convert them back and forth from int to bitset so I could do arithmetic on the integers.

This isn't not a performance effective method, but in this case that wasn't important.

Comment: Um theres no BitSet.subXXX method. I understand why you would want a nice bit twiddling byte abstraction but java.util.BitSet does not add up.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get(int, int)